# Can SplitViewControllers be used on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am building an App for the iPhone in Swift.

I want a small slice of the top of my app to be a User Area, and the rest of the screen to be whatever view/page the user is currently viewing.

This leads me to think that I need to use a `UISplitViewController`, but everything I read about `UISplitViewController`s tells me that they only work on iPads.

Is this correct?

If this is the case can someone tell me how to create the effect I am after on an iPhone (programmatically in Swift would be great). Sorry for asking (what seems to me) to be a basic question, after much searching online I couldn't find anything definitive on the subject.

Many thanks

Comment: Now Apple introduced SplitViewController in ios8 and you can use it in your project this is demo http://www.appcoda.com/building-rss-reader-using-uisplitviewcontroller-uipopoverviewcontroller/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html) says:

> In iOS 8 and later, you can use the UISplitViewController class on all iOS devices; in previous versions of iOS, the class is available only on iPad.

So you can use if its at least iOS8.